# How to change size of FloatingActionButton in KivyMD?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

No parameter changes have any effect. Also the `set_size` function specified in the documentation does not work.
`user_font_size` resizes only the icon inside the button, but not the button itself.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFloatingActionButton


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = MDScreen()
        btn_1 = MDFloatingActionButton(icon='account',
                                       pos_hint={'x': .2, 'y': .1},
                                       )
        btn_2 = MDFloatingActionButton(icon='account',
                                       pos_hint={'x': .3, 'y': .1},
                                       size=[16., 16.],
                                       user_font_size=64
                                       )
        btn_2.set_size((100, 100))
        screen.add_widget(btn_1)
        screen.add_widget(btn_2)
        return screen


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

elited:

`size_hint` does not work and throws an error:

`[CRITICAL] [Clock       ] Warning, too much iteration done before the next frame. Check your code, or increase the Clock.max_iteration attribute`

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code?

Answer (score 0):

For KivyMD version 0.104.1:

Unfortunately the KivyMD documentation does not seem to accurate. You can set the size of a FloatingActionButton by using size hint (ex: `size_hint=(0.1, 0.1)`) to correspond to the window size. If you want to use specific pixel values, see below:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFloatingActionButton


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = MDScreen()
        btn_1 = MDFloatingActionButton(icon='account',
                                       pos_hint={'x': .2, 'y': .1},
                                       )
        btn_2 = MDFloatingActionButton(icon='account',
                                       pos_hint={'x': .3, 'y': .1},
                                       size=[16., 16.], # Not necessary, doesn't have an effect
                                       user_font_size=64
                                       )
        btn_2.size = (100, 100) # Modified line
        screen.add_widget(btn_1)
        screen.add_widget(btn_2)
        return screen


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

For whatever reason, you can't set the button size when you initialize the MDFloatingActionButton instance, you can only do it afterwards.

Comment: No, thats didn't work. And ```size_hint```  throws an error and didn't work too

Comment: My bad, I was on KivyMD version 0.104.1, not the latest version. I looked at the source code for the latest version, and they made it so that the value is basically hard coded. Everytime the size of MDFloatingActionButton is modified, it will be reverted back to the default value. you will probably need to figure out a way to get around this. I'll post an edit to this answer if I find a solution.